# Powershell won't pull every computer name from Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Basically I have written a script that will take an input that is either a username or full name it will output the user's full name, username and computer name. Within AD, the only place where the user's name or username is found is within the description of the computer. This is shown by the variable $new.

The problem I am having is that the code works for some people, but not others. It will still give the username and full name, but leaves the computer name blank. I don't know if this is a problem with my code, or if it is something within AD. Below is the code that I am using:

```
$input = Read-Host "Enter username or full name" 

if ($input -like "* *") #Used if the user types in the full name
{
    $blah = Get-ADUser -Filter{name -like $input}
    $new = $input.ToUpper() + "; " + $blah.SamAccountName.ToUpper()
    $name = $input.ToUpper()
    $username = $blah.SamAccountName.ToUpper()
}
else                    #Used if the user types in a username
{
    $blah = Get-ADUser $input
    $new = $blah.name.ToUpper() + "; " + $input.ToUpper() 
    $name = $blah.name.ToUpper()
    $username = $input.ToUpper()
}

    $new = $name.ToUpper() + "; " + $username
    $output = Get-ADComputer -Filter{description -like $new} -Properties name
    $strComputer = $output.Name

Write-Host " "
Write-Host "Name:               "$name
Write-Host "Username:           "$username
Write-Host "Computer Name:      "$strComputer
Write-Host " "
```

I apologize in advanced for my strange variable names. Thanks!

Comment: To debug you need to start with something like `Write-Host $output.GetType()`. For example, Get-ADComputer may return a collection of objects (because description isn't unique) in which case `$output.Name` will be null.

Comment: I think that this is the problem. The people that it is able to get the computer name for only have one computer linked to their credentials. Everyone that it does not work for seems to be linked to more than one computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter on `Get-ADComputer` uses `-like`, but doesn't use any wildcards. Is this intentional?

Since you're getting multiple values back, try this:

```
$strComputer = [System.String]::Join(", ", $output.Name)
```

Comment: Not necessarily. I can change it to -like with the same outcome.

Comment: But are you confident that the description field will be an exact match? Without wildcards you aren't going to get any results unless it's exact.

Comment: Yes, for the name I am using it is an exact match to what the description of the computer says.

Comment: Try this one. That should work if you're getting multiple computers back.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the help, you both pointed me in the right direction. This is what I did in the end based on y'all's suggestions and it works just fine!

```
$input = Read-Host "Enter username or full name" 

if ($input -like "* *") #Used if the user types in the full name
{
    $blah = Get-ADUser -Filter{name -like $input}
    $new = $input.ToUpper() + "; " + $blah.SamAccountName.ToUpper()
    $name = $input.ToUpper()
    $username = $blah.SamAccountName.ToUpper()
}
else                    #Used if the user types in a username
{
    $blah = Get-ADUser $input
    $new = $blah.name.ToUpper() + "; " + $input.ToUpper() 
    $name = $blah.name.ToUpper()
    $username = $input.ToUpper()
}

$new = $name.ToUpper() + "; " + $username
$outputs = Get-ADComputer -Filter{description -eq $new} -Properties name

foreach ($output in $outputs)
{
    $strComputer = $output.Name

Write-Host " "
Write-Host "Name:               "$name
Write-Host "Username:           "$username
Write-Host "Computer Name:      "$strComputer
Write-Host " "
}
```